$\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite Radon measure on LCH $X$, $A$ is a Borel set, $\mu_A(E)=\mu(A\cap E)$, why $\mu_A$ is a Radon measure too?
$\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite Radon measure on LCH $X$, $A$ is a Borel set, $\mu_A(E)=\mu(A\cap E)$, why $\mu_A$ is a Radon measure too?
The problem is how can I find a sequence of open sets whose measure converges to $\mu_A(E)$, and contain E.

I learned a solution from my friend.
By Riesz Representation Theorem, $\mu$ is corresponding to a positive linear form $\phi$ on $C_C(X)$, and $\phi=\int_Xfd\mu$, construct $\phi_A=\int_Xfd\mu_A=\int_Xf|_Ad\mu$, which is obviously also a positive linear form on $C_C(X)$, hence $\mu_A$ is a Radon measure.
